# Is it possible to create a toggle (switch) in MarkDown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to achieve something like this for a documentation that is written with MarkDown:[image]

The toggle will show this sample code either in Objective-C or Swift.
I couldn't find anything in MD's documentation that shows that this is possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with regular Markdown or GitHub-flavoured Markdown.

Markdown, generally, outputs HTML. The language itself is [deliberately very simple](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags ... The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose.

What you want to do needs JavaScript.

You could potentially write some JavaScript that works with your Markdown output, though depending on where you plan to host the HTML you may have trouble with that, too.

Comment: GitHub-flavored markdown does allow this now (see other answer)

Comment: @gdvalderrama, you can use an HTML `<details>` tag in most Markdown environments, but is that really what OP was asking for? How does that let the user toggle between languages? The closest is probably two separate, unrelated `<details>` tags, where the user would always have to expand one and nothing would prevent both from being expanded at the same time. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @Chris that's actually a great point, I got caught up on the other answer instead of the question itself

Answer (score 17):

It is possible with GitHub-flavored markdown in 2021

To make a toggle switch just write this HTML markup in your markdown file(HTML is supported in .md files):

```
<details>
    <summary>Toggle Switch</summary>
    Foldable Content[enter image description here][1]
</details>
```

In the above markup, the content inside `<details>` tag would be foldable(can be toggled) and the content inside `<summary>` tag would be taken as the content of the toggle button.

Comment: This needs to be updated as the correct answer at least for GitHub.

Comment: could you make a gist at GitHub with full code

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using excel

text output:

I found out how this works - add cariage return and it works like a champ.

To test manually, I dropped a term in excel:
[image]